# Docker CMD when base image has a CMD?

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile which starts with:

```
FROM puppet/puppetserver
```

When I look at the [source container](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker/blob/master/puppetserver/Dockerfile) it is built from [another](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker/blob/master/puppetserver-standalone/Dockerfile):

```
FROM puppet/puppetserver-standalone:5.0.0
```

The second contains a `CMD` command:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["foreground" ]
```

In my own container I end with:

```
COPY start.sh /
CMD /start.sh
```

The `CMD` run but with unexpected results:

> puppetserver: '/bin/sh' is not a puppetserver command. See 'puppetserver --help'.

I know that I have bash availible because I'm using `RUN commands.sh` before `CMD` in the same Dockerfile.

How do `CMD` commands stack when inheriting from base images?

Is my `CMD` not run as a normal bash command and instead run in conjunction with the `CMD` of the base image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset the ENTRYPOINT from the parent image

```
COPY start.sh /
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD /start.sh
```

Comment: Thanks trying now, will this mean the `/docker-entrypoint.sh` from the parent container won't run? (Can probably just reference it in my `start.sh` if so)

Comment: Yes if you want to run it, you will run it in your `start.sh`

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact

> CMD should be used as a way of defining default arguments for an ENTRYPOINT command or for executing an ad-hoc command in a container.

and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

> There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.